# How to show 2 arrayList in a table jsp file with 2 foreach

Tags: jsp, foreach, html-table

I want to create a table with two columns that shows the elements of two array list.

```
list1= c;
list2= a;

<table id="zebra-verticale" border=1 width="100%" height="100%" table bgcolor="#FFFFFF"  >
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Id_c</th>
            <th>Id_a</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <c:forEach var="id_c" items="${c}">
         <tr> <td> <c:out value="${id_c}" /></td>
</c:forEach></td>
        <c:forEach var="id_a" items="${a}">
            <td><c:out value="${id_a}" /></td>
</tr></c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like something like:

```
a    ||  c

el_a ||  el_c
el_a ||  el_c
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess its pretty hard to do with a list and you can try with a map ,

In your servlet , pass the request attribute as map , something as

```
Map<a,c>
```

Then in your jsp , iterate the map like this ,

```
   <table border="2">
            <tr>
            <thead>a</thead>
            <thead>c</thead>
            </tr>                
        <c:forEach var="mapV" items="${map_Name}">
            <tr>
             <td> ${mapV.key} </td> 
             <td> ${mapV.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
```

Hope this helps!!